# SQLGrammarException:Table does not exist (ManyTOMany) relationship Spring MVC

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, many-to-many, sqlexception

I am trying to perform a post user operation using REST services in Spring MVC. 
I have a many to many relationship between user and phone objects. 
I have created a User table and Phone table in the database.

Both the user and phone objects are initialized as ArrayList.
However, when I run this code(try to create a new user) I get this error: 
**`javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Table 'schemaname.USER_PHONE' doesn't exist`**

I don't understand why the implementation is excepting the table USER_PHONE to be present on prior basis. Isn't it supposed to create on its own ? 
Please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think it should create that table automatically? Especially since you explicitly set hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to none.

Comment: @JBNizet What shall I set the value to then ?

Comment: You'll leave it that way, but you'll create the missing join table, just as you created the two other ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by setting "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" to "create-drop".
Thanks :)